Unable to start embedded browser in Burpsuite JAR executable on ubuntu 24.04
I am running Burpsuite community edition latest version (v2024.6.6) on Ubuntu 24.04 and when i try to open the browser from proxy tab it doesn't open without showing any errors in terminal and in GUI it simply says Burp Browser Error with the dialogue box being empty.
Here are some output from my terminal regarding java version am using:
$ java --version
java 22.0.2 2024-07-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 22.0.2+9-70)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0.2+9-70, mixed mode, sharing)

My operating system:
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Release:    24.04
Codename:   noble

The command used by me:
$ java -jar -Xmx4g burpsuite_community_v2024.6.6.jar


I am running the above command as normal user and without superuser privileges

I've already allowed Burp Browser to run without sandbox from Settings > Burp's Browser > Allow Burp's Browser to run without a sandbox

When i run the command as "root" or "sudo" the previous error is gone however this time i can see the embedded browser opening a window but showing some unexpected behaviour such as opening and closing on it's own without showing any UI of the chromium

Apart from java 22, I also tried using java 21 and using ubuntu's openjdk instead of oracle but none of them seems to work.


Below is the screenshot of the error am receiving:

I would be grateful to get some help. Thanks

I saw similar error while using etcher but this time etcher itself guided me on how to fix this issue and I applied the same fix on BurpSuite and it somehow worked!
First, find chrome-sandbox binary location of your burpsuite:
cd ~/.BurpSuite/burpbrowser

then go to the directory staring with 127.0...
cd 127.0.6533.99  # dir name `127.0.6533.99` is likely to be different in your case

then do:
sudo chown -R root:root chrome-sandbox
sudo chmod 4755 chrome-sandbox


The way I solved it was to create an AppArmor profile for it (replace "path-to-burp" with your Burp install path):
abi <abi/4.0>,

include <tunables/global>

/path-to-burp/burpbrowser/*/chrome flags=(unconfined) {
  userns,
  
   # Site-specific additions and overrides. See local/README for details.
   include if exists <local/chrome>
}
 
/path-to-burp/burpbrowser/*/chrome-sandbox flags=(unconfined) {
  userns,

   # Site-specific additions and overrides. See local/README fordetails.
   include if exists <local/chrome>
}

Save it to a profile file like /etc/apparmor.d/burp-chrome and then run sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/burp-chrome to load it immediately. Burp's browser should then work as normal.
